# How to know if IE is on its latest version?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I can see my IE version from the About IE window, it shows 11.0.9600.18697, however I don't know if it is the latest version.

I have been searching on Google, but found nothing, there's no such information anywhere include Microsoft websites.

Weird enough, any help?

Answer (score -1):

I've currently got 11.962.10586.0

Updates are done through Windows Update as far as I'm aware. So run that and see if you're good?

Alternatively I'm pretty sure you can just download IE 11 and run the installer.